# Which is the correct ROC metric type to use for Imbalanced Dataset (macro,micro, weighted) for multiclass classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, natural-language, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a classification task where I have more than 350 classes with **HUGE** data imbalance. I want to check my model performance but I am confused which metric to use. So I Googled some questions and found conflicting answers:

[This Answer says that I should use `macro` if I have imbalance](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40900/whats-the-difference-between-sklearn-f1-score-micro-and-weighted-for-a-mult)

> If you are worried with class imbalance I would suggest using 'macro'

[Another answer says in its `NOTE` that I should **NOT** use `macro`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66803701/micro-vs-macro-vs-weighted-f1-score)

> If you look at the macro, it says: This does not take label imbalance into account. So better to use micro if you have an imbalanced data

And when you look at the [Documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html), it has `multiclass` parameter as `oov, ovr`. **Do I need to pass it too if I have multiclass classification**?

I am using `cross_val_score` with `StrifiedKFold` so I can pass only:

```
‘roc_auc’
‘roc_auc_ovr’
‘roc_auc_ovo’
‘roc_auc_ovr_weighted’
‘roc_auc_ovo_weighted’
```

I have my code which consists of pipeline as:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('clf',RandomForestClassifier(class_weight = 'balanced',n_jobs = 3, random_state = SEED))])

cv = StratifiedKFold(5, shuffle = True, random_state = SEED)
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, x, y, scoring='roc_auc_ovo', cv = cv, n_jobs = 3)
```

Please help with the confusion how do I analyse my results properly.

Comment: What's wrong with using the value of the crossentropy loss function?

Comment: Great idea but for that, I'll have to access `predict_proba`. I am using `Optuna` + `cross_val` so accessing the functions and using inheritance might get messy, no? Also, won't `Crossentropy` affect in imbalanced ( I think there's no reason to but still in doubt)

Comment: You have to access the probability values to do anything ROC-style, so that does not seem like a drawback to the loss function. Don't you get the loss values, though? I know `Keras` gives them at every step of neural network training. Does `sklearn` not do the same? // Crossentropy loss is affected by the class imbalance, yes, but if there is class imbalance, it should be. [Remember that class imbalance is not much of an issue.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)

Comment: Not actually. `tf 2.0 / Kears` have become customisable but `sklearn` is too hard to customise. Also, I am using random forest here which itself is the part of pipeline and pass it to the apise function `cross_val_score` and then all it goes to `optuna` trial. So on and on, accessing the `proba` function is very hard unless you inherit the class and then change the `cross_val` function. When I use `roc_ovo`, it uses their own implementation on the function so it might have access to the `predict_proba` function of the `model`

Comment: AUROC (c-index; concordance probability) works fine even with extreme imbalance.  But better and more intuitive measures exist - see [here](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue).

Comment: @FrankHarrell Any idea on how to use that here? In my case? I asked it on `stackoverflow` and due to **THEORETICALLY** in nature, it's been closed.

Comment: If you need to code a class inheritance that is difficult, Stack Overflow is the perfect place to ask. What you're learning from statisticians is that, while c-index is the appropriate analogue of ROCAUC, there are better options. It seems like all of these will require `predict_proba`.

Comment: The simplest and most intuitive approach, shown in the link above, is to make 100-200 bins of predicted probability of class membership for each class and to show a high-resolution histogram for each set of predicted probabilities.  The extent to which probabilities occur that are closer to 0 or 1 is the extent to which the predictions are useful.  You can summarize this with one number if you had to, i.e., the variance of the predicted probabilities.

Comment: I (unsurprisingly) second Dave's proposal of the cross-entropy, which is a proper scoring rule, specifically the log score: [Why is LogLoss preferred over other proper scoring rules?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274088/1352) It's completely fine with "unbalanced" data. @Dave: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.