# loss function in terms of distribution and label

Tags: loss-functions

I received an answer to a question about learning, and I noticed the writer gave loss functions as $l(p,y)$, where $p$ is a predicted distribution, and $y$ is a class index.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/589070/96019

Does anyone have a reference where loss functions for classification of any other problem are given this way? The writer convinced me there is a usefulness in the formulation, so I would like to see a reference material to study further.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "this way"?  As far as I can tell, you describe the most well understood meaning of a loss function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [whuber notes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590295/loss-function-in-terms-of-distribution-and-label#comment1092013_590295), this is a very standard formulation. (How else would you denote a loss that depends on a probabilistic prediction and an observed outcome?)

Such loss functions are called *scoring rules*, and [the tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info) has pointers to literature, and an example of this notation: $s(y, \hat{y})$ denotes the score for a probabilistic prediction $\hat{y}$ and the corresponding outcome $y$. As an example, I just randomly looked into [Gneiting, Balabdaoui & Raftery (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2007.00587.x) and see this notation in section 3.4 on scoring rules.