# Understanding StatQuest video: why cross entropy is used over Sum Squared Error

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, cross-entropy

I was watching [cross entropy video from StatQuest](https://youtu.be/6ArSys5qHAU?t=471). While explaining why to use cross entropy over SSE in multi output scenario with softmax output activation, Josh gives this graph of both losses:

[image]

He the says that loss is very high for CE than MSE.
But I am not able to get how he got that orange straight line. I tried to [plot in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ng8ajoxfls).

[image]. Note that what I have plotted in blue is just `(1-p)`, which I dont believe Josh thought of for MSE. In fact, I dont know if my Cross Entropy plot is correct. Josh says its -log(p). But the x axis is not clearly labeled as p by Josh. What he exactly means by X axis labels "worst prediction" and "great prediction"? How exactly make sense out of this graph by Josh?

PS: I didnt plot $(1-p)^2$ because its not straight line as in video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$p$ here is the predicted probability of an outcome to belong to the class it actually turns out to belong to. To illustrate: suppose we have three possible classes, and our model says that a given new instance has a probability $0.5$ of belonging to the first class, $0.3$ of belonging to the second, and $0.2$ of belonging to the third class. The instance actually turns out to belong to the second class. So in this case, $p=0.3$.

Now, the question is one of how to measure the "badness" of our probabilistic prediction. The two losses you note are quite common. We note that a perfect prediction would have been $p=1$, i.e., we would have predicted the new instance to belong to the class it actually turned out to belong to *with certainty*. (Of course, this also implies that our probabilistic prediction of the instance to belong to the *other* classes would have been zero.) Both losses are zero for such perfect predictions:

$$ -\log p = -\log 1 = 0\quad\text{and}\quad (1-p)^2=(1-1)^2=0. $$

The question is how these losses behave when our prediction is *not* perfect. Of course, the lower $p$, the worse the prediction is - and correspondingly, the higher the loss should be.

This is what is depicted. The MSE grows quadratically with decreasing $p$, and ends up at $1$ if $p=0$ (i.e., if we had believed it to be *impossible* for the instance to belong to the class it actually does belong to). So the MSE is bounded. The line should indeed not be straight, but a parabola. This is presumably to draw attention to the fact that the Cross-Entropy grows *much* faster as $p$ decreases. In fact, the Cross-Entropy is infinite for $p=0$: seeing an outcome we believed to be impossible yields an infinitely large Cross-Entropy loss.

Cross-Entropy is also known as the log loss, and the MSE is the Brier score. (Many concepts are developed independently by different people, and given different names.) Both are *proper scoring rules*, i.e., losses that incentivize us to output the true class membership probabilities. (Other losses, like [accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352), do *not*. Also, a straight line loss like you plotted, which would correspond to the Mean Absolute Error, or MAE, would reward biased predictions.) There is a comparison between the two losses at [Why is LogLoss preferred over other proper scoring rules?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274088/1352)

Answer (score 1):

You should not plot $$(1-x)^2$$ Instead, you should plot $$(x-1)^2$$
The reason is that we look at **how the loss behaves according to the assigned probability to the ground truth class**. For binary cross entropy, it boils down to computing $-log(y_{pred})$. For MSE loss, where we compute in general $(y_{pred} - y)^2$, if we assume y=1, it means: $(y_{pred}-1)^2$.

Basically, you can use this Python snippet to plot the losses:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)

mse_loss = lambda x: (x-1)**2
log_loss = lambda x: -np.log(x)
#Plot the losses
plt.plot(x, mse_loss(x), label='MSE')
plt.plot(x, log_loss(x), label='Log')
plt.xlabel('Proba assigned to the correct class')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: How does $(x-1)^2$ differ from $(1-x)^2?$