How to increase weight of false negatives in MCC?
I am working on a multi class classification model that is able to predict pre-diabetes and diabetes. I am currently using Matthews Correlation Coefficient (MCC) as my primary metric for evaluation. However, I would like to increase the weight of false negatives in MCC relative to false positives because it is more valuable to minimize false negatives than false positives in diabetes classification.
I am currently debating between two different ways of achieving this:

Modify the formula of MCC to increase the weight of false negatives relative to false positives.

$$
\text{Weighted_MCC} = \frac{
    c \times s - \sum_{k}^{K} (p_k \times \text{fp_weight}) \times (t_k \times \text{fn_weight})
}{\sqrt{
    (s^2 - \sum_{k}^{K} (p_k \times \text{fp_weight})^2) \times
    (s^2 - \sum_{k}^{K} (t_k \times \text{fn_weight})^2)
}}
$$

Combine MCC with another metric that focuses on false negatives, such as recall or f2 score, through geometric mean or harmonic mean.

Which way is better?

Sensitivity, specificity etc. and any weighted combinations of these suffer from all the same issues as accuracy, i.e., they all presume a very specific cost structure to decisions in the face of uncertainty - but they do not make the costs explicit. Better to work with probabilistic classifications and separate the decision aspect from them. Decisions need to take classifications and costs into account, and even if there are only two classes, there may well be more than two possible decisions

Yes, that was boilerplate. And it equally applies to your Weighted_MCC. If the MCC (which I am not familiar with) is just an unweighted version of this, the same criticism applies to it.

I removed tag "metric"

@StephanKolassa, your right that MCC suffers from the same issues as accuracy. What metrics would you recommend I use instead for multi class classification? Also, would you recommend that I train and evaluate my model using probabilistic classification and then calibrate it in the end?

I would recommend you use probabilistic classifications, and evaluate them using proper scoring rules. For instance, the log or the Brier score work perfectly fine in the multiclass case. Here are some comparisons for this exact case: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274088/1352

@StephanKolassa, after the model has been trained and evaluated, how would you recommend I get the threshold for making hard classifications? Would it be appropriate to use metrics such as ROC AUC score or MCC for deducing the threshold or would it be better to use scikit-learn's CalibratedClassifierCV?

You cannot derive an optimal decision threshold from your statistical data alone. (Note "decision", not "classification".) This depends on the costs of your actions in the light of class membership. You may have more than two possible actions, even if there are only two classes. This may be helpful.

@StephanKolassa, when using scikit-learn’s RFECV, using log loss as the scoring method yields very different results compared to using improper classification metrics like F1 score and MCC. What metric do you recommend I use for RFECV?

I would absolutely recommend using probabilistic predictions as elicited by a proper scoring rule (either log loss or the Brier score). Of course you can only compare these to other models yielding "hard" classifications after you have compared the probabilistic output to a threshold which you should be careful about selecting.
