# Accuracy of ordinal predictions of a continuous outcome (without fixed thresholds)

Tags: predictive-models, ordinal-data, accuracy

I have ordinal predictions by *experts*: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. The outcome to be predicted is, however, continuous: 0-36.

I don't know what threshold the experts use for the categories 1-5, but I know that the outcomes in 1 should be smaller than in 2, in 2 smaller than in 3, and so forth. How can I compute the accuracy of each expert?

Intuitively, I would like to allow for different thresholds for each expert. So I would basically *count the ranking errors*.

Are there any established methods to do this?

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the [tag:scoring-rules] tag, because *(proper) scoring rules* have a very precise technical meaning, being evaluation measures for *probabilistic* predictions, [e.g., here for ordinal data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/64774/1352) - and you don't have that. That said, you might be able to use a kind of rank correlation, like Spearman's or Kendall's? I know it's late, but can you give any info on what exactly your experts rate, what the outcomes are, and how many realizations per expert etc. there are?